# Difference in selecting column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the technical difference between selecting columns in Pandas DataFrame by providing column as atribute or as a string in the brackets (sorry, don't know exact expresion of what it is called)?

Example:

```
df  = pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=0)
df1 = df[df.village == 1]
df2 = df[df['village'] == 1]
```

`df1 is df2` returns `False`.

Also, would appreciate if someone could explain any further possible manipulation differences between newly created df1 and df1. I mean can I return different results compared to each method?

I also wasn't able to compare their `==` value. Don't know how.

Comment: look here for an answer to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

== is not the same as is

Comment: To find out if  two dataframes have the same content, you can use [`DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html).